# CSS Property Overflow not working

Tags: css

I am using `Overflow:auto` to scroll a div and it works fine in desktop but not working in Android browser. Is there any proper way to fix this ?

Comment: have a look here https://github.com/filamentgroup/Overthrow/

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't supports overflow property. See if this helps you.

https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll